# About the creation of a "Bessel functions" tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

I am quite new to tag creation, and I was wondering about adding the *Bessel functions* tag for related problems. I had already created a *Bessel* tag, when Asaf Karagila suggested me (just [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150132/integral-with-bessel-function/914342#comment1887257_150132)) to write a topic on Meta. I think he is clearly right since the creation of a new tag may involve a massive re-tagging of old, un-categorized questions, and this may require a community effort.

What do you think about the introduction of the Bessel functions tag?

Are you willing to cooperate in tagging related old questions?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to meta, Jack.

Comment: I would like [tag:bessel-functions] I think. It makes sense to me. If and when retagging starts, please stage and stagger edits so that the front page (valuable real estate!) doesn't become flooded.

Comment: Is [tag:special-functions] an unsatisfactory umbrella tag? I'm not saying it is/isn't, just asking :-) Depends on the volume, I guess.

Comment: My opinion is that the special-functions tag covers too many topics. Since there are many tags dedicated to specific functions (like Legendre polynomials) and many questions dedicated to Bessel functions, I think that they deserve a specific tag.

Comment: Maybe I should also point you to this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/how-much-bumping-is-too-much

Comment: Congrats to you [taxonomist badge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=44121). The tag already reached 50 questions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. If a tag for Bessel functions exists, it should not be named [bessel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bessel). With this name we'll be forever retagging questions that are about Bessel's inequality rather than Bessel functions. Even then: do not underestimate the willingness of users to add wrong tags that have some word in common with what they want (see 3).
2. I am not  opposed to the tag [bessel-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bessel-functions) existing. We already have [zeta-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zeta-functions), [gamma-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamma-function), [theta-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theta-functions), [l-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l-functions), [hypergeometric-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hypergeometric-function). However, one should realize that the tag [special-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-functions) should still be used along with it. Users are not going to be updating their favorite/ignored preferences every time a tag for a named function is created.
3. Cautionary tale: [chebyshev-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chebyshev-function) is full of questions about Chebyshev-whatever, but not -function. At a glance, I have not found a single question about actual [Chebyshev functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) there.  It is not unusual for rarely-used tags with few followers to degenerate into such a mess.
4. That said, if there are enough users enthusiastic about Bessel functions specifically, then go for it...
5. **Added**: After [looking into it more](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bspecial-functions%5D+Bessel) I think the tag is viable: there are over 300 questions with "Bessel" and [special-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-functions) in them. Most of them have no tag other than [special-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-functions); thus, there is room for another tag. Whether or not one should edit old questions just for adding the tag is another matter. I'd suggest to do this gradually and along with improving quality of questions/answers in other ways, if possible.

Comment: I do not think that 3. applies here since there are yet many questions related to Bessel's functions, it is a frequently discussed topic on MSE.

Comment: +1, and if only for the statement "do not underestimate the willingness of users to add wrong tags that have some word in common with what they want". In fact, in many times it's not even with what they want, but with arbitrary words in their questions (apparently, anything including the word "set" is fair game for [set-theory], and anything requires a "logical thinking" is fair game for [logic]).

Comment: @Jack: I think you should wait before starting to use [bessel-functions]. At least for more input. There are barely any votes or even views on this thread.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Ok, I'll wait a few days and opinions before starting serial retagging. I will just add my contribute to unanswered questions, for now.

Comment: (I see someone went ahead and cleaned up the chebyshev-function tag.)