# What is (chebyshev-function) tag for?

Tags: discussion, tagging

When you look at questions currently tagged [chebyshev-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chebyshev-function), you will see questions from various areas there. (Number theory, Chebyshev polynomials, Chebyshev inequality,...) The [tag-info for this tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/chebyshev-function/info) is currently empty.

My first guess would be that this tag is supposed to be used for questions about [Chebyshev functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) such as $\vartheta(x)$ and $\psi(x)$, which are used in analytic number theory. (But there might be also some other meanings of this term I am unaware of.)

I think that it would be good to:

- Agree what this tag should be used for.
- Fill in the tag-excerpt and tag-wiki, explaining when the tag should be used.
- Clean up this tag. (Remove the tag from the questions belong there. Add the tag to the questions about Chebyshev functions.)
- If incorrectly tagged questions will keep appearing even after the tag-wiki is added, we might also create a [comment template](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/8587#8587) explaining correct usage of this tag.

But I wanted to get some input from other community members first.

---

I searched a bit whether this tag has already been discussed here on meta. The only thing I found was a mention of this tag in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16695/about-the-creation-of-a-bessel-functions-tag/16696#16696):

> Cautionary tale: [chebyshev-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chebyshev-function) is full of questions about Chebyshev-whatever, but not -function. At a glance, I have not found a single question about actual [Chebyshev functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) there. It is not unusual for rarely-used tags with few followers to degenerate into such a mess.

---

**EDIT:** Since nobody objected to the idea that this tag - if we keep it - should only be for questions about Chebyshev functions in number theory, I went ahead and created [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1146602/revisions) and [tag-exceprt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1146603/revisions).

I have also started retagging questions which do not belong here, see [this list](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20012289#20012289). They are mostly about Chebyshev polynomials and Chebyshev inequality. Since I am not very familiar with these two topics, some people with more experience in these areas might have a look at those questions and choose better tags, if needed.

Of course, if there is support for the suggestion to get rid of the tag entirely - as suggested in the AlexR's answer - this still can be done. (Although in that case we will have remove the tag-wiki, since the tags having tag-wiki [are not removed from the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki).)

Comment: Those who really are about chebychef functions seem sufficiently tagged by [tag:analytic-number-theory], so maybe we should just soft-delete the tag. I didn't see any question wich would need retagging after removing [tag:chebychev-function]. If we keep it I suggest notifying about [tag:chebychev-polynomials] in the wiki since it seems one of the most common mistags.

Comment: @AlexR Maybe it would be reasonable to post your comment as an answer. (So that we see from the voting whether other users agree/disagree with the removal of the tag.) Thanks also for the suggestion about ([tag:chebyshev-polynomials]), it sounds very reasonable.

Comment: Seeing some of the questions in this tag makes me wonder whether it would be reasonable to create also a tag for [Chebyshev's inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=chebyshev+inequality). (But this is not relevant for the discussion about (chebyshev-function) tag.)

Comment: [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20050664#20050664) is a list of questions currently tagged (chebyshev-function).

Answer (score 4):

Suggestion for the tag-info, in case we decide to keep the tag. (I made the post CW, feel free to make any reasonable improvements.)

Tag-excerpt:

> For questions about Chebyshev functions $\vartheta(x)$ and $\psi(x)$, which are often used in number theory. For questions about Chebyshev polynomials, use the (chebyshev-polynomials) tag.

Tag-wiki:

> This tag is intended for questions about [Chebyshev functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) $\vartheta(x)$ and $\psi(x)$, which are often used in number theory. These functions are defined as
>   $$\vartheta(x)=\sum_{p\le x} \log p$$
>   and
>   $$\psi(x) = \sum_{p^k\le x}\log p=\sum_{n \leq x} \Lambda(n) = \sum_{p\le x}\lfloor\log_p x\rfloor\log p.$$
>
> For questions about Chebyshev polynomials, use the [chebyshev-polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chebyshev-polynomials) tag.

Answer (score 3):

Those questions which really are about [chebyshev-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chebyshev-function)s seem sufficiently tagged by [analytic-number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytic-number-theory), so maybe we should just **soft-delete the tag** (remove, don't blacklist).

I didn't see any question which would need retagging after removing [chebyshev-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chebyshev-function), but if we decide to keep it I suggest notifying about [chebyshev-polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chebyshev-polynomials) in the wiki since it seems one of the [most](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957433/chebyshev-polynomial-recurrence-relation) [common](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532103/calculation-of-chebyshev-coefficients) [mistags](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415458/how-to-best-approximate-higher-degree-polynomial-in-space-of-lower-degree-polyno).

Comment: I disagree about removing the tag only because all those questions belong to [tag:analytic-number-theory]. Compare with [tag:derivatives]: it's not because we have [tag:calculus] that we don't need [tag:derivatives] (probably there are better examples).

Comment: @barto "seem sufficiently tagged by" is a stronger observation than "are a subset of".

Comment: I agree with @AlexR. Unlike calculus, analytic number theory is a small enough section of mathematics (in the sense of questions on math.stackexchange) that further subdividing is unnecessary.

Comment: I went through questions [tagged only chebyshev-functions](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/201122/posts-tagged-with-only-one-selected-tag?tag=chebyshev-function). I have added some tag, but if you have idea for better tags, please, go ahead and retag them.

Comment: @MartinSleziak All three are not about the function, but are about the inequality, so the tag can actually be removed from them regardless of our procedure with the tag itself.